# Contact form not posting to trello

Tags: php, trello

I have a contact form on my website using Unirest I am trying to POST data to Trello API creating a card. Keep getting error 500. Here are index.html and contact.php that I have. https://trelloapi.yetitech.nz/yetitech-trello-int/

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="contact-form">
            <div class="container">
                <form action="contact.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="eMail" class="form-control" />
                    <input type="text" name="Business_Name" placeholder="Business Name" class="form-control" />
                    <input type="tel" name="Contact_Phone" placeholder="Contact Phone" class="form-control" />
                    <select name="type">
                        <option value="Website">Website</option>
                        <option value="software">Software</option>
                        <option value="hosting">Hosting</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" name="Message" placeholder="Message" class="form-control"/>
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"> Submit</button>
                        <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> -->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

php script:

```
<?php

require_once '/src/Unirest.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $business_name = $_POST['Business_Name'];
    $contact_phone = $_POST['Contact_Phone'];
    $message = $_POST['Message'];
}

$query = array(
    'key' => '{MYKEYHERE}',
    'token' => '{MYTOKENHERE}',
    'idList' => '{MYIDISHERE}',
    'name' => $name,
    'desc' => $message
  );
  
  $response = Unirest\Request::post(
    'https://api.trello.com/1/cards',
    $query
  );

  var_dump($response)

?>
```

I am using these API docs: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-post

Can anyone see what I am missing, my error 500 isn't giving a lot of indication as the Data is parsing via the form:

[Error_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6TzP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tap on response Tab in browser you can see nearby header you show in image. then findout what be wrong with error message.

Comment: It says "This request has no response data available"